# Funções de primeira classe: Por que tipos de entrada devem ser contravariantes?

Tags: funções, tipagem, variância

Para demonstrar o problema vou usar código Scala (apesar dessa ser [uma regra](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/Inheritance%20%28Semantics%20of%20Data%20Types%29.pdf) formalizada por [Luca Cardelli](http://lucacardelli.name/)).

```scala
trait Function1[-A, +R] {
  def apply(x: A): R
}
```

Em Scala isso significa que uma função com um elemento é contravariante na entrada e covariante na saída.

Ou seja, só podemos considerar que uma função `f: (X => Y)` é subtipo de uma função `g: (X' => Y')` se `X` for um **supertipo** de `X'` e `Y` for um **subtipo** de `Y'`.

Por que isso ocorre?

Comment: ps: Parte do meu programa *"Mais perguntas para o Beta"*, se alguém discordar das *tags* fiquem a vontade para editar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A justificativa pro tipo de entrada ser contravariante [e de saída, covariante] é para satisfazer ao [Princípio da substituição de Liskov](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov). Esse princípio afirma que "subclasses devem ser sempre menos restritas que suas superclasses". Em outras palavras, onde um objeto da classe base podria ser usado, um objeto da subclasse também deveria poder ser usado.

Por isso, se temos um código legado que chama um método `foo` da classe base, passando `Bar` como parâmetro e recebendo `Baz`, e esse método é sobrescrito (e não somente sobrecarregado) nas subclasses, é necessário que elas:

1. Aceitem **pelo menos** `Bar` como argumento; elas podem aceitar **mais** que `Bar`, mas não menos. Se uma subclasse decidir aceitar, por exemplo, qualquer coisa (i.e. `Object`), não tem problema: pois ela ainda estará aceitando `Bar`.

   Como qualquer **superclasse** de `Bar` atende a esse requisito, o tipo do parâmetro de entrada é contravariante.
2. Retornem um objeto **compatível** com `Baz`; elas podem retornar algo **mais específico** que `Baz`, mas não algo incompatível com ela (i.e. que tenha uma interface mais restrita, campos/métodos faltando, etc). Como objetos de **subclasses** podem ser usados no lugar de objetos da classe base (pelo próprio princípio de Liskov), os mesmos podem ser usados como valor de retorno (i.e. o tipo da saída é covariante).

Essa decisão [de usar covariância na saída e contravariância na entrada] garante [**segurança de tipo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), reduzindo/eliminando erros de tipo em tempo de execução. Estratégias **mais restritas** (ex.: invariância) também possuem o mesmo efeito, mas sem a conveniência de se customizar o comportamento das subclasses conforme a necessidade.

É bom mencionar também que existem linguagens (como a [Eiffel](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_%28linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29)) que dão suporte a **tipos de entrada covariantes**. Essa estratégia pode ser conveniente em muitas situações, ainda que não seja 100% a prova de falhas. Exemplo (usando a sintaxe de Java - mais familiar que a de Eiffel):

```java
class AbrigoAnimais {
    void adicionarAnimal(Animal a) { ... }
    Animal obterAnimal() { ... }
}

class AbrigoGatos extends AbrigoAnimais {
    void adicionarAnimal(Gato g) { ... }  // Entrada covariante (não typesafe)
    Gato obterAnimal() { ... }            // Saída covariante (typesafe)
}

AbrigoGatos abrigo = new AbrigoGatos();
// Erro em tempo de compilação
abrigo.adicionarAnimal(new Cachorro());
// Erro em tempo de execução
((AbrigoAnimais)abrigo).adicionarAnimal(new Cachorro());
```

Answer (score 11):

Minha resposta (pragmática) para a questão:

O motivo de só ser seguro retornar um subtipo do tipo de retorno da função original (`+R`) fica claro analisando um caso concreto:

Considerando que `Gato` é um subtipo de `Animal`.

```scala
class Gato extends Animal
```

Repare no seguinte exemplo onde `f <: g` :

```scala
g: (Int => Animal) 
f: (Int => Gato)
```

Fica claro que para poder usar `f` no lugar de `g`, `f` precisa retornar um subtipo de `R`, i.e., `Gato <: Animal`; caso contrário `f` poderia retornar um tipo fora de conformidade com a assinatura de `g` (um tipo que não fosse um `Animal`).

A regra oposta (`-A`) pode ser entendida por outro exemplo prático em que novamente `f <: g`:

```scala
g: (Gato => Int) 
f: (Animal => Int)
```

Fica claro que para poder usar `f` no lugar de `g`, `f` precisa receber um supertipo de `A`, i.e., `Animal >: Gato`; caso contrário `f` poderia receber um tipo fora de conformidade com a assinatura de `g`. (não há nenhum problema em `f` também atender outros subtipos de `Animal`, desde que `Gato` seja um deles para satisfazer a assinatura de `G`).

**P.S.:** Essa segunda parte pode soar um pouco estranha para programadores Java, uma vez que a linguagem não permite que um método seja sobrescrito por outro com argumentos de tipos mais amplos. Essa foi uma decisão de linguagem (que Scala também abraçou, funções e métodos são duas coisas diferentes); o motivo mais provável para a decisão é que permitir esse tipo de sobrescrita junto a capacidade de sobrecarga traria uma série de complicações para a linguagem ([mais informações no SOE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485666/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-not-allowing-supertypes-on-java-method-overrides)).