# Porque é que isto viola os Strict Standards?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, solid

Tenham em conta as seguintes definições de classes:

```
class SuperDate {}
class SubDate extends SuperDate {}

class Foo
{
    public function setDate(SubDate $date) {}
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function setDate(SuperDate $date){}
}

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar();
$bar->setDate(new SubDate());
$foo->setDate(new SubDate());
```

Este código dá o seguinte erro:

```
Strict standards: Declaration of Bar::setDate() should be compatible with Foo::setDate(SubDate $date)
```

Obviamente, a causa é o facto da assinatura de `Bar::setDate` ser diferente da de `Foo:setDate`. [No StackOverflow em inglês existe uma pergunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092605/php-strict-standards-declaration-of-should-be-compatible/21092699) que refere uma violação do [Princípio de Substituição de Liskov](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov) como causa do "strict warning", mas a situação é ligeiramente diferente porque a subclasse é mais restritiva que a classe mãe.

No entanto, no meu caso, a assinatura em Bar é mais "larga" que em Foo e, por isso, completamente intersubstituivel. Isto é, sendo Bar um subtipo de Foo, então os objetos do tipo Foo podem ser substituídos pelos objetos de tipo Bar sem ser necessário alterar as propriedades do programa.

Por isso, a minha pergunta é: **Porque é que este código viola os "Strict Standards"?**

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2413

Comment: Talvez porque o tipo em `Bar` não está definido? Tentou Object?

Comment: @bfavaretto Dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: @bfavaretto Editei para clarificar melhor o problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O parâmetro do método da classe filha tem que ser exatamente do mesmo tipo do parâmetro do método da classe pai.

> Na programação orientada a objetos, SOLID é uma sigla para Single responsibility, Open-closed, Liskov substitution, Interface segregation e Dependency inversion.
>
> O princípio da substituição de Liskov diz que, em um programa de computador, se `Bar` é um subtipo de `Foo`, então os objetos do tipo `Foo` podem ser alterado por objetos do tipo `Bar` sem alterar as propriedades do programa (correção, execução da tarefa, etc.).
>
> Em programas com tipagem forte, ao fazer um *override* um método de `Foo`, se você alterar a assinatura de `Bar`, você está de fato fazendo um *overload*, uma vez que o método original e o novo método possuem assinaturas diferentes. Entretanto, como o PHP possui tipagem fraca, isso não é possível de se conseguir, uma vez que o compilador não sabe qual dos métodos você está, de fato, chamando (por isso, a razão pela qual você não pode ter dois métodos com o mesmo nome, mesmo que suas assinaturas sejam diferentes).
>
> Então, para evitar a violação do princípio da substituição de Liskov, um aviso de *strict standard* é feito, avisando o programador que há um problema em potencial devido à alteração na assinatura do método da classe filha.

(traduzido de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423494/why-is-overriding-method-parameters-a-violation-of-strict-standards-in-php)

Ou seja, ao invés de usar:

```
class Foo
{
    public function setDate(SubDate $date) {}
}
class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function setDate(SuperDate $date) {}
}
```

Use:

```
class Foo
{
    public function setDate(SubDate $date) {}
}
class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function setDate(SubDate $date) {}
}
```

Comment: Sim, mas a minha pergunta é: Porque é que tem de ser assim?!

Comment: Pois quando você herda métodos de uma superclasse, quando você os sobrescreve precisa passar os mesmos argumentos que o método superior requer.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, veja se responde sua dúvida.

Comment: Como assim o compilador não sabe qual dos métodos você está de fato chamando?

Comment: O que eu entendi foi: se existisse *overloading* em PHP, devido à caracteristica da tipagem fraca da linguagem, o compilador não saberia qual método de fato chamar.

Comment: :-) Essa foi boa... a resposta que você traduziu e inclui aqui quem escreveu foi o próprio autor da pergunta!

Answer (score 2):

Eu penso que a resposta a esta pergunta é muito simples.

Esse código viola o *standard* porque o *standard* é ***strict*** (restrito), e em sua estrita definição de *compatible* (compatível), a assinatura dos métodos  **precisa ser idêntica**.

**Esse é o standard.** Então, por isso é que esse código viola o *standard*: porque o *standard* determina que as assinaturas sejam idênticas. E ponto final.

Não tem nada a ver com a assinatura do método ser mais restritiva ou permissiva, ou com os meandros do Princípio de Substituição de Liskov ou outro princípio SOLID. Essa discussão é interessante, mas a resposta objetiva para a pergunta é absolutamente simples: viola porque viola; viola porque o *standard* exige que as assinaturas não sejam diferentes...

Em suma: o código viola os *strict standards* porque um dos *strict standards* define que "***a assinatura dos métodos numa hierarquia de classes precisa ser idêntica***".

---

Agora, se a pergunta for "**por que definiram um standard como esse?**", quer dizer, "por que decidiram incluir essa obrigatoriedade de assinaturas idênticas entre os strict standards?" - aí então o foco é outro.

Será que foi uma boa decisão? Será que foi uma decisão ruim? Quem tomou essa decisão? Por qual motivo? O que uma restrição dessa pode favorecer?

Eu acho que uma argumentação a favor seria mais ou menos assim: "dentro do padrão estrito, é possível saber se um parâmetro é válido ou não para um método de uma determinada hierarquia, seja qual for a classe específica da instância do objeto cujo método está sendo invocado" - assim, o programa teria como saber se `$hyperDate` é um parâmetro válido para `SetDate` ou não, mesmo sem usar reflexão e condicionais.

O que é válido para uma, é válido para todas. O que não é válido para uma, não é válido para nenhuma outra. Independente de ser `parent` ou `child`.

Quão importante é "saber se um parâmetro é válido ou não para um método, seja qual for a classe específica de uma instância"? Quão útil é exigir essa coerência e uniformização na assinatura do método em toda uma hierarquia de classes?

Não sei se é importante ou mesmo útil... sei que é ***strict***.

Comment: Você tem um link para a lista de definições dos strict standards? Acho que é a única coisa que falta na sua resposta.

Comment: Não tenho. Apenas obtive a informação a partir da mensagem de erro: `Strict standards: Declaration of Bar::setDate() should be compatible with Foo::setDate(DateTime $date)` - e dos links compartilhados aqui mesmo. Desconheço quais sejam os demais.

Answer (score 0):

A solução mais conveniente neste cenário seria.

```
interface  StdDate{ }

abstract class SuperDate {}

class SubDate extends SuperDate implements StdDate {}

class Foo
{
    public function setDate(StdDate $date) {}
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function setDate(StdDate $date){}
}

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar();
$bar->setDate(new SubDate());
$foo->setDate(new SubDate());
```