# O que são covariância e contravariância?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, variância

Vi algo do tipo [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2413/fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-primeira-classe-por-que-tipos-de-entrada-devem-ser-contravariantes) e sei que isso se relaciona de alguma forma com orientação a objetos.

O que são? Como afetam meu código, e como posso utilizá-las para codificar melhor?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Em linguagens orientadas a objeto, se uma função ou variável espera receber um objeto de um tipo você não precisa passar a ela um objeto exatamente desse tipo: segundo o [princípio da substituição de Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) podemos passar qualquer outro objeto compatível que ele também serve. Por exemplo, se uma variável é do tipo `Animal`, podemos atribuir a ela um objeto do tipo `Cachorro`, já que os objetos cachorro implementam todos os métodos esperados pela interface da superclasse.

```
Animal a = new Cachorro("rex");
```

Até aqui tudo bem, mas o princípio de Liskov é uma descrição do comportamento das coisas e para descrever o sistema de tipos de forma mais rigorosa vamos precisar de regras concretas, que é onde vão aparecer a co- e a contra-variância.

O primeiro lugar onde aparece esse problema são os tipos dos métodos. Suponha que a interface Animal tenha um método `foo`:

```
interface Animal {
    Animal foo (Animal x);
}
```

As subclasses de `foo` também tem que implementar esse método. Mas os tipos dos parâmetros e do valor do retorno precisam ser exatamente os mesmos?

```
//invariante - ok
class Cachorro1 implements Animal {
    Animal foo (Animal x);
}

//parâmetro covariante - erro
class Cachorro2 implements Animal {
    Cachorro foo(Cachorro x){ ... }
}

//retorno contravariante - erro
class Cachorro3 implements Animal {
    Object foo(Object x){ ... }
}

//retorno covariante, parâmetro contravariante- ok
class Cachorro4 implements Animal {
    Cachorro foo (Object x);
}
```

A versão 1 obviamente serve, já que o tipo do método `foo` é exatamente o mesmo. Mas e a versão 2 e a 3? A classe `Cachorro2` não obedece o princípio de Liskov devido ao tipo do parâmetro: esperamos poder passar qualquer `Animal` como parâmetro de Foo, mas um objeto `Cachorro2` não aceita Gatos como parâmetro, apenas outros `Cachorros`. De forma parecida, a classe 3 quebra o princípio de substituição com o tipo de retorno: esperamos que `foo` sempre nos retorne um `Animal`, mas um objeto `Cachorro3` pode nos retornar um outro `Object` qualquer. Já a classe 4 não tem nenhum problema: ela é menos restrita no tipo do que ela aceita e não tem problema ser mais específico no tipo de retorno.

Resumindo, quando que um método é substituível por outro? Se tivermos dois tipos de função F = A -> B (função que recebe A e retorna B) e F' = A' -> B', então

```
 F' <: F
 se e somente se
 (A <: A') e (B' <: B)
```

Repare que no tipo do parâmetro o A e o A' estão na ordem trocada em relação ao F e o F' enquanto no caso do tipo do retorno (B) eles estão na mesma ordem. O tipo do retorno varia na mesma direção do tipo do método (covariância) enquanto o tipo do parâmetro varia na direção oposta (contra-variância)

O outro lugar onde aparece a variância são nos tipos parametrizados, ou *generics*. E tivermos um tipo parametrizado como `List`, e dois tipos A <: B, o que podemos dizer sobre os tipos `List<A>` e `List<B>`? Quem é subtipo de quem? Nesse caso a resposta depende do tipo parametrizado e a resposta do Maniero tem uns bons exemplos:

`List<A>` é um tipo invariante em relação ao parâmetro A. Não importa se A < B: nem `List<A>` vai ser subtipo de `List<B>` nem vice versa.

`Enumerable<A>` é covariante com o seu parâmetro A: se A <: B então um `Enumerable<A>` <: `Enumerable<B>`

`PrintAnimals<A>` é contravariante com seu parâmetro A: se A <: B então `PrintAnimals<B>` <: `PrintAnimals<A>`

Por padrão, quando você criar um tipo parametrizado o compilador vai assumir que o seu tipo parametrizado é invariante em relação aos tipos parâmetro. Se você quiser que seu tipo seja covariante ou contravariante você precisa adicionar uma anotação junto com o parâmetro. Em Scala (a pergunta que você *linkou*) essa anotação é um `+` ou `-` e em C# (como os exemplos do Maniero) essa anotação é `in` ou `out`

Answer (score 34):

A variância se refere a como um tipo se relaciona com seus subtipos.

Vou usar exemplos em C# que é o que eu conheço.

Primeiro vamos à um exemplo de invariância:

```cs
IList<Animal> lista = new List<Dog>();
```

O que acontece se você tentar adicionar um elemento em `lista` que seja do tipo `Cat`? O compilador vai recusar. E faz bem já que esta lista só deveria aceitar `Dog`s. Não há como garantir que a inclusão de um `Cat` não vai causar problemas na `lista` que está sendo tratada como uma lista de `Animal`s.

Mas se sabemos que uma operação é segura em determinadas relações, podemos indicar que a operação é covariante. Um bom exemplo é uma enumeração. Você não pode mudar o tipo de uma enumeração, então pode permitir mais liberdade.

```cs
void PrintAnimals(IEnumerable<Animal> animals) {
  for(var animal in animals)
    Console.WriteLine(animal.Name);
}

IEnumerable<Cat> cats = new List<Cat> { new Cat("Tom") };
PrintAnimals(rats);
IEnumerable<Mouse> mouses = new List<Mouse> { new Mouse("Jerry") };
PrintAnimals(mouses);
```

O código de `PrintAnimals` só pode funcionar porque `IEnumarable` é covariante:

```cs
public interface IEnumerable <out T>: IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

Este `out` é a indicação da covariância do tipo. Está dizendo que o tipo `T` pode ser representado por um supertipo (um tipo mais geral) sem problemas. Esta declaração está indicando para o compilador que um `IEnumerable` de um tipo mais específico, por exemplo `IEnumerable<Cat>` pode ser tratado como um tipo mais genérico, por exemplo `IEnumerable<Animal>`.

Obviamente isto é uma escolha consciente do desenvolvedor. Ele só deve fazer esta opção se tiver certeza que a operação não causará problemas.

Sem esta indicação de covariância o compilador impedirá a declaração de `lista` acima.

A **covariância** indica que uma coleção de dados pode ter seus elementos referenciados pelos seus supertipos (tipos que ele possui por alguma forma de herança).

A **contravariância** faz a indicação inversa. Ela permite um tipo mais específico ser usado no lugar de um tipo mais geral. Exemplo para operações de comparação:

```cs
public interface IComparer<in T>
{
    int Compare(T x, T y);
}
```

Neste caso o `in` indica a contravariância e permite que o seguinte código seja válido:

```cs
void CompareCats(IComparer<Cat> comparer) {
  var cat1 = new Cat("Tom");
  var cat2 = new Cat("Frajola");
  if (comparer.Compare(cat1, cat2) > 0) 
    Console.WriteLine("Tom é maior!");
}

IComparator<Animal> compareAnimals = new AnimalSizeComparator(); //sabe como comparar Animals
CompareCats(compareAnimals);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/VarianceCovariance.cs).

Isto está dizendo que um objeto `Animal` pode usar uma comparação de `Cat` sem problemas. O resultado obtido será correto. Ou seja, um tipo mais geral pode se beneficiar de uma operação mais especializada adequadamente.

Com a utilização destas técnicas programas podem ser mais flexíveis e podem ser compilados mantendo a segurança de tipos. Sem uma certeza dada pelo desenvolvedor, o compilador vai sempre preferir considerar os tipos como invariantes.

O assunto é contra intuitivo por isso todo mundo acha confuso.

- Fonte adicional de informação no [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).
- Outra fonte especificamente para C# é a ótima [série do Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-1/).
- Fonte oficial na [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [FAQ oficial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) da Microsoft.
- [Exemplos em C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669858/simple-examples-of-co-and-contravariance).
- [Exemplos em Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java).
- Um [exemplo prático](https://rogeriomc.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/msdn-webcast-trabalhando-com-covariancia-e-contravariancia-no-cs4/).

Answer (score 6):

### Qual é do papo de Variância?

Vou tentar explicar do jeito que eu fixei esse assunto na minha mente... da forma mais intuitiva para mim, na esperança de que o assunto se torne o mais trivial e fácil o possível.

Em linguagens onde os tipos podem ser compostos via um parâmetro estático, a variância diz como o tipo composto varia de acordo com o tipo componente (é mais fácil entender com os exemplos! =D ).

Vou explicar usando C# pois é a linguagem que eu domino. Imagino que outras linguagens tenham conceitos parecidos. No C# só se aplica variância a interfaces e delegates genéricos, ou seja, que aceitam tipos como parâmetros (de forma estática).

Funciona assim:

```
interface IList<T> { ... }
```

Note que a interface `IList` recebe um tipo por parâmetro denominado de `T`. Isso é chamado de parâmetro genérico no C#.

Ao usar a interface podemos fazer a composição, como nesse exemplo:

```
IList<int> listaDeInteiros;
```

- **Covariância:** suponha uma interface `IS<T>`. `IS` e `T` são covariantes quando `IS` varia junto com `T`. Assim sendo isso é válido:

  ```
  Animal a = (Girafa)g;
  IS<Animal> ia = (IS<Girafa>)ig;
  ```
- **Contra-variância:** suponha outra interface `IE<T>`. `IE` e `T` são covariantes é quando `IE` varia contrariamente a `T`. Assim sendo isso é válido:

  ```
  Animal a = (Girafa)g;
  I<Girafa> ig = (I<Animal>)ia;
  ```

Uma questão que sobra é o que faz um tipo ser covariante ou contra-variante com relação ao seu parâmetro?

Ou melhor, que característica do tipo faz os exemplos acima serem verdadeiros?

Vou explicar usando as interfaces dos exemplos acima.

### O que caracteriza a covariância

O uso de `T` apenas como saída do tipo `IS<T>`.
Por isso, no C#, se anota o parâmetro genérico com `out`:

```
interface IS<out T> // T só poderá ser usado como saída
{
    T LerValor(); // método que tem saída do tipo T
}
```

Vamos testar pra ver se vai dar problema:

```
IS<Animal> ia = (IS<Girafa>)ig;
Animal a = ia.LerValor(); // parece bom... IS<Girafa>.LerValor()
                          // retorna Girafa, que é um Animal.
                          // Beleza!
```

Em linguagem humana, algo que devolve somente girafas, pode ser tratado como algo que devolve animais.

### O que caracteriza a contra-variância

O uso de `T` apenas como entrada do tipo `IE<T>`.
Por isso, no C#, se anota o parâmetro genérico com `in`:

```
interface IE<in T> // T só poderá ser usado como entrada
{
    void EscreveValor(T valor); // método cuja entrada é do tipo T
}
```

Vamos testar pra ver se vai dar problema:

```
IE<Girafa> ig = (IE<Animal>)ia;
ig.EscreveValor( (Girafa)g ); // parece bom... IE<Animal>.EscreveValor(x)
                              // recebe Animal, então se eu só puder passar
                              // Girafa tá de boa, pois Girafa é Animal.
                              // Beleza!
```

Em linguagem humana, algo que recebe animais, pode ser tratado como algo que recebe apenas girafas.

### Composição de vários níveis de variância

Fica mais fácil entender usando delegates neste caso.

Delegates são definições de funções... é uma assinatura de função, assim por dizer.

Vou definir eles assim:

```
delegate T DS<out T>(); // tipo de função que retorna um valor T
delegate void DE<in T>(T valor); // tipo de função que recebe o valor T
```

Vamos a algumas afirmações e alguns códigos para demonstrar:

- A saída da saída é uma saída

  ```
      DS<DS<Girafa>> ssg = () => () => new Girafa();
      DS<DS<Animal>> ssa = ssg;

      // vou receber uma girafa (como sendo um animal)
      Animal a = ssa()();
  ```
- A entrada da saída é uma entrada

  ```
      DS<DE<Animal>> sea = () => a => Console.WriteLine(a);
      DS<DE<Girafa>> seg = sea;

      // vou passar uma girafa (mas o delegate sabe usar qualquer animal)
      var g = new Girafa();
      seg()(g);
  ```
- A saída da entrada é uma entrada

  ```
      DE<DS<Animal>> esa = sa => Console.WriteLine(sa());
      DE<DS<Girafa>> esg = esa;

      // vou passar uma girafa (mas o delegate sabe usar qualquer animal)
      var g = new Girafa();
      esg(() => g);
  ```
- A entrada da entrada é uma saída

  ```
      DE<DE<Girafa>> eeg = eg => eg(new Girafa());
      DE<DE<Animal>> eea = eeg;

      // vou receber uma girafa (através do delegate)
      Animal a;
      eea(a2 => a = a2);
  ```

Tentei fazer uma imagem para explicar, não sei se está confusa, se estiver me falem que eu mudo ou tiro ela.

[image: Composição de níveis de variância]

**Composições titânicas**

Vamos a uns exemplos mais, digamos, complexos:

- A entrada da saída da entrada da entrada... o que seria? Já respondo: é entrada.

  ```
      DE<DE<DS<DE<Animal>>>> eeseg = null;
      DE<DE<DS<DE<Girafa>>>> eesea = eeseg;
  ```
- E a entrada da saída ^5 da entrada da saída da entrada da entrada... o que seria? Direto ao ponto: é saída.

  ```
      DE<DE<DS<DE<DS<DS<DS<DS<DS<DE<Girafa>>>>>>>>>> eesessssseg = null;
      DE<DE<DS<DE<DS<DS<DS<DS<DS<DE<Animal>>>>>>>>>> eesesssssea = eesessssseg;
  ```

É possível responder muito rápido a essas questões. Basta contar as entradas.

- Número par de entradas é saída
- Número ímpar de entradas é entrada

Mas e as saídas?

R: saídas não afetam em nada

- A saída da saída ^10000: é saída pois tem número par de entradas (0 é par)
- A saída ^100 da entrada da saída ^101: é entrada pois possui número ímpar de entradas (apenas 1 entrada)