# Qual a diferença entre as formas de declaração de generics com out e in?

Tags: c#, genéricos

Qual a diferença entre as declarações de generics quando se faz uso de **`out`** e **`in`**?

Exemplo:

```cs
public class GenericClass<T> { }

public class GenericClassOut<out T> { }

public class GenericClassIn<T in> { }
```

Comment: Creio que sua dúvida já foi respondida em: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956993/out-t-vs-t-in-generics

Comment: @IvanTeles Sim, mas seria legal termos aqui uma resposta em português. Sinta-se à vontade para redigir uma, ou mesmo traduzir alguma do inglês (citando a fonte, claro).

Comment: E tem a `in` também, por favor!

Comment: Relacionado: ["O que são covariância e contravariância?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/215). Não considero essa pergunta duplicada (pois esses conceitos são mais gerais, aplicando-se não somente a tipos genéricos mas também a outros contextos, como entrada e saída de funções), de modo que dei uma resposta mais contextualizada abaixo, sem entrar no mérito de explicar com detalhes os conceitos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `out` e o `in` tornam o tipo genérico [**covariante** e **contravariante**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/215), respectivamente.

Um exemplo de tipo covariante é o `IEnumerable`:

```
public interface IEnumerable <out T>: IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

<sup>[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10957035/520779), [Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32903/215)</sup>

Como a função de um `IEnumerable` é iterar sobre os membros de uma lista, e todo objeto de um tipo mais específico pode ser atribuído a uma variável de um tipo mais geral (i.e. um objeto `string` pode ser guardado numa variável `object`), então um objeto que "produz" uma sequência de strings também pode ser usado como "um objeto que produz uma sequência de objetos". Os elementos retornados serão os mesmos (as strings da lista), mas seu tipo estático será `object` e não `string`.

O contrário não é verdadeiro: um `IEnumerable` que produz uma sequência de objetos não pode ser usado [de forma segura] num contexto que espera uma sequência de strings (já que ele também pode produzir coisas que não são strings).

Um exemplo de tipo contravariante é o `IComparer`:

```
public interface IComparer<in T>
{
    int Compare(T x, T y);
}

IComparer<object> objects = ...;
IComparer<string> strings = objects;
```

Nessa caso a relação é oposta: se um `IComparer` é capaz de comparar objetos quaisquer, ele também é capaz de comparar strings (pois uma string é um objeto). De modo que ele pode ser usado num contexto que exige um comparador de strings. O contrário não é verdadeiro, pois um comparador que só sabe comparar strings não pode ser usado para comparar objetos arbitrários.

Por fim, um exemplo de tipo **invariante** (que não é nem co- nem contravariante) é o próprio `IList`:

```
IList<string> strings = new List<string>();
IList<object> objects = new List<objects>();
```

Como a lista tanto *aceita* quanto *retorna* objetos do tipo especificado, não se pode atribuir `strings = objects` (pois a lista poderia já conter elementos que não são strings) nem `objects = strings` (pois a lista não deveria poder receber elementos que não são strings). A conversão em ambos os sentidos é proibida, de modo a garantir a segurança de tipos. De modo que nem o `in` nem o `out` devem ser usados na declaração do tipo genérico:

```
public interface IList<T> ...
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Precisei ler várias vezes para entender!! =D rs.. Obrigado!