# Como fazer um Cast de uma classe tipada no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, tipagem, classes-abstratas

Eu possuo a classe `Carro` que herda da classe `Objeto` e outra classe `CarroTeste` que implementa a classe abstrata `TesteBase` que por sua implementa a interface `ITeste`, ambas (`TesteBase` e `ITeste`) tipadas com restrição para usarem somente objetos da classe `Objeto`, o problema ocorre quando tento instanciar um `CarroTeste` em uma variável de ITeste `ITeste<Objeto> teste = new CarroTeste();`, a IDE dis que não posso fazer uma conversão implicita de tipo. 
O código das classes esta a baixo.

```
public class Objeto
{
    protected string _nome;
    public string nome { get{return _nome;} }
}

public class Carro : Objeto
{
    public Carro()
    {
        _nome = "Carro";
    }
}

public interface ITeste<T> where T : Objeto
{
    string GetNome();
    List<T> List { get; }
    T GetChange(T obj);
}

public abstract class TesteBase<T> : ITeste<T> where T : Objeto
{
    protected Objeto _obj = null;
    public abstract string GetNome();
    public abstract List<T> List { get; }
    public abstract T GetChange(T obj);
}

public class CarroTeste : TesteBase<Carro>
{
    public override string GetNome()
    {
        return "Meu nome é : " + _obj.nome;
    }

    public override List<Carro> List
    {
        get { return new List<Carro>(); }
    }

    public override Carro GetChange(Carro obj)
    {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Durante os meus testes com a resposta dada pelo bigwon alterei a interface para usar o modificador `out` e implementei na classe `CarroTeste` um método chamado `CarroToObjeto` que através da função `ConvertAll` da própria `List` me retorna uma nova lista com o tipo correto, porem, obviamente, uma List<Objeto> não possuí todas as propriedades e métodos de Carro.

Resumindo: mesmo que seja possível realizar o Cast a lista retornada não iria satisfazer as necessidades do sistema então eu vou utilizar diretamente a classe `CarroTeste` ao invés da interface `ITeste`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está com problema de [variância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/101). Para resolver você deve permitir que a interface seja usada de forma covariante. Veja:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        ITeste<Objeto> teste = new CarroTeste();
    }
}

public class Objeto {
    protected string _nome;
    public string nome => _nome;
}

public class Carro : Objeto {
    public Carro() => _nome = "Carro";
}

public interface ITeste<out T> where T : Objeto {
    string GetNome();
}

public abstract class TesteBase<T> : ITeste<T> where T : Objeto {
    protected Objeto _obj = null;
    public abstract string GetNome();
}

public class CarroTeste : TesteBase<Carro> {
    public override string GetNome() => "Meu nome é : " + _obj.nome;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/coggFp). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Awiiub). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/Cast.cs).

Note a linha `public interface ITeste<out T> where T : Objeto {` usando o [modificador `out`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69840/101) para indicar a variância.

Não sei se resolve do jeito que você deseja, mas soluciona o problema imediato.

Comment: Kr essa sua dica resolveu um problema mas causou outro pois a classe que postei era um resumo da classe que uso. Vou editar a pergunta colocando a classe completa a baixo esta o erro ao usar o modificador `out`.

Error 1 Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'WindowsFormsApplication1.ITeste<T>.GetChange(T)'. 'T' is covariant. C:\Users\Begins\Desktop\Trabalho\Testes C#\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Teste.cs 23 33 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Aí você mudou o problema. Agora não posso ver isto. Mas parece que o problema é mais embaixo ainda.

Comment: Me desculpe bigwon eu não imaginava que as outras funções interfeririam no problema pois desconhecia completamente a variância.

Answer (score 1):

O seu código está correto, o .NET só não faz a conversão implícita (sem você pedir).

Converta o objeto de forma explícita:

```
ITeste<Objeto> teste = (ITeste<Objeto>) new CarroTeste();
```

Esse `(tipo)` instrui a conversão do que vier depois. Neste caso, é o que chamamos de conversão explícita.

Esse comportamento existe para evitar conversões sem que o programador queira. Caso isso acontecesse e causasse algum problema, seria muito, muito difícil de rastrear.

Comment: ao usar a função obtive o erro:
"Error 1 'WindowsFormsApplication1.CarroTeste.implicit operator WindowsFormsApplication1.ITeste<WindowsFormsApplication1.Carro>(WindowsFormsApplication1.CarroTeste)': user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed C:\Users\Begins\Desktop\Trabalho\Testes C#\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Teste.cs 54 23 WindowsFormsApplication1
"

Comment: verdade, mas a primeira forma funciona?

Comment: Infelizmente não eu tentei varias formas de Cast explicito a unica compilou foi `ITeste<Objeto> teste = new CarroTeste() as ITeste<Objeto>;` e mesmo assim não funciona, o erro ocorre em tempo de execução o que é mais perigoso.

Diante deste fato eu não usarei mais esse tipo de Cast em nenhuma situação.

Comment: Um martelo pode machucar se usado de forma incorreta. Portanto, nunca devem ser usados.