# O que é Covariance, Contravariance e Invariance?

Tags: terminologia

Lendo [este artigo da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) eu me deparei com esses três termos, com os seguintes significados (tradução via Google Translate):

- **Covariance**

Permite usar um tipo mais derivado do que o especificado originalmente.
Você pode atribuir uma instância de `IEnumerable<Derived>` a uma variável do tipo `IEnumerable<Base>`.

- **Contravariance**

Permite usar um tipo mais genérico (menos derivado) do que o especificado originalmente.
Você pode atribuir uma instância de `IEnumerable<Base>` a uma variável do tipo `IEnumerable<Derived>`.

- **Invariance**

Significa que você pode usar apenas o tipo originalmente especificado; Assim um parâmetro de tipo genérico invariante não é nem covariante nem contravariante.

Não é possível atribuir uma instância de `IEnumerable<Base>` a uma variável de tipo `IEnumerable<Derived>` ou vice-versa.

Gostaria de saber, em outras palavras, o que significam essas palavras?

Comment: Isso? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/101 Exemplo prático: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75097/101

Comment: @bigown Eu procurei e não achei. Irei votar para fechar aqui, muito obrigado :p