# Qual é o propósito do comando super quando usado na declaração de parametros de um método?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, java-8

Em Java o comando `super` tem a função de chamar o construtor da superclasse. No entanto, na declaração do método `forEach()` da classe `ArrayList` ele é utilizado de uma forma diferente do comum, veja a assinatura do método que contem o comando `super`:

```
public void forEach(Consumer<? super E> action)
```

A sintaxe acima do método `forEach()` me deixou confuso em relação ao uso do `super` e eu gostaria de saber qual é o propósito dele quando ele é usado desse modo como citado acima?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isso faz parte do conceito de [contravariância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32880/o-que-s%C3%A3o-covari%C3%A2ncia-e-contravari%C3%A2ncia) aplicado ao conceito de genéricos do Java.

## Covariância em genéricos

Só para contextualizar, covariância ocorre quando usamos `extends` e permitimos um tipo mais específico (subclasse) ser usado no lugar de um tipo mais genérico.

Vamos ao exemplo de um método é covariante:

```
java.util.ArrayList#addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends E>)
```

Agora suponha a seguinte hierarquia de classes:

```
class Animal { }
class Gato extends Animal { }
class Cachorro extends Animal { }
```

Se tivermos uma lista de `Animal`, podemos acrescentar listas de qualquer subtipo:

```
List<Gato> gatos = new ArrayList<>();
List<Cachorro> cachorros = new ArrayList<>();

List<Animal> animais = new ArrayList<>();
animais.addAll(gatos);
animais.addAll(cachorros);
```

Covariância é de longe mais fácil de entender e mais utilizada.

## Contravariância em genéricos

Ocorre quando usamos `super` e permitimos um tipo mais genérico (superclasse) ser usado no lugar de um tipo mais específico. É praticamente o oposto da covariância.

Vamos ao exemplo de contravariância citado na pergunta:

```
java.util.ArrayList#forEach(Consumer<? super E> action)
```

Agora suponha a seguinte hierarquia de classes:

```
class Animal { 
    void darBanho() { }        
}
class Gato extends Animal { }
class Cachorro extends Animal { }
```

A ideia aqui é poder fazer com que uma lista de `Cachorro` ou uma lista de `Gato` possam ambas receber um `Consumer<Animal>`.

Portanto, o objetivo da contravariância aplicada aos genéricos é possibilitar o reuso de código genérico.

Exemplo:

```
List<Gato> gatos = new ArrayList<>();
List<Cachorro> cachorros = new ArrayList<>();

gatos.forEach(Animal::darBanho);   
cachorros.forEach(Animal::darBanho);
```

Outro exemplo:

```
List<Animal> animais = new ArrayList<>();
List<Gato> gatos = new ArrayList<>();
List<Cachorro> cachorros = new ArrayList<>();

Collections.copy(animais, gatos);
Collections.copy(animais, cachorros);
```

No exemplo acima, o método `copy` tem a seguinte assinatura:

```
void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
```

Em outras palavras: a lista de destino (`dest`) pode ser de qualquer tipo genérico que seja uma superclasse do tipo genérico de origem (`src`). Neste caso, `Animal` é superclasse de `Gato` e `Cachorro`.

Portanto o uso do `super` no método reforça que a lista de destino sempre poderá receber elementos da lista de origem já que você sempre pode atribuir um tipo específico a um tipo mais genérico.

Contravariância é também um pouco contraintuitiva, mas fica mais fácil de entender se você pensar que muitas vezes é interessante tratar um um objeto ou coleção de objetos como seu tipo mais genérico para algum tipo de processamento genérico.

Comment: Poderia fazer um código java7?

Comment: @DavidSchrammel Feito. Olhe o segundo exemplo de contravariância.

Answer (score 3):

Significa que qualquer superclasse de E será aceita.

Exemplos:

```
List<? super Integer> foo1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // Integer é superclasse de Integer
List<? super Integer> foo2 = new ArrayList<Number>();   // Number é superclasse de Integer
List<? super Integer> foo3 = new ArrayList<Object>(); // Object é superclasse de integer.
```