# Adicionar elementos a um List<? extends Number>

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Por que não é possivel adicionar elementos a uma lista do tipo `List<? extends Number>`?

por exemplo :

```
public class GenClass{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    List<? extends Number> ml=new Vector<Integer>();

    ml.get(0); //ok
    ml.add(new Integer(7)); // erro de compilação
    ml.add(new Double(7d));// erro de compilação
    ml.add(new Number(7));// erro de compilação
    ml.add(new Object());// erro de compilação
  }
}
```

Comment: Agora eu entendi o que é covariancia e contravariancoa . Eu so não entendi porque dá erro de compilação quando eu tento adicionar um tipo que extends Number.

Comment: Também não entendi isso, `ml.get(0)` retorna um `Number`, mas quando eu testei fazer `ml.add(ml.get(0));` também deu erro de compilação! Afinal, que tipo de objetos uma lista "List<? extends Number>" é capaz de receber? Você pode nos ajudar @Articuno? :) - *Obs.: ao fazer `List<Number> ml = new Vector<Number>();` (sem usar `extends`) a lista consegue receber `Integer` e `Double` normalmente.*

Comment: `Number` é uma classe abstrata que representa uma coleção de tipos, você não pode definir uma list que aceite tipos number e do lado direito definir o vector pro tipo integer, não tem como a List garantir que o tipo number seja integer, uma vez que number é um supertipo herdado de varios subtipos numericos como Double, Float. Essa lista se torna apenas para leitura, não é possivel adicionar nada pois não é possivel garantir que o tipo de number adicionando seja o mesmo informado na atribuição

Comment: E se eu faço  List<? extends Number> ml=new Vector<Number>();

Porque eu não consigo também adicionar os seus subtipos , dando erro de compilação? mas quando faço   List<? super Number> ml=new Vector<Number>();
Consigo adicionar Double Integer , etc.?

Comment: Minha explicação no comentário anterior vale pra todos os casos onde você usar `List<? extends Number>` independente do que você declare do lado direito.

Comment: O que o compilador leva em conta é a variável de referencia.

Comment: Se você parar pra notar, o problema que ocorre em `List<? super Number>` é exatamente o oposto que ocorre com `List<? extends Number>`, porque o problema que ocorre aqui é exatamente o oposto do que expliquei. Mais uma vez reforço: você precisa ler todas as repostas dos dois links e entender o conceito de covariância e contravariancia pra entender este problema.

Comment: @Articuno se eu fizesse "`List<? extends Number> ml = new Vector<Integer>();`" e em seguida fizesse "`ml.add(new Double(7d));`" eu esperaria receber uma ClassCastException em tempo de execução, mas pelo que entendi do que você falou, o Compilador não vai permitir que eu adicione qualquer coisa a lista "ml" pra evitar esse tipo de Exception. Isso significa que em nenhum momento o Compilador me permitirá fazer "`ml.add(...)`"?, não há absolutamente nada que eu possa passar por parâmetro que o compilador aceite?

Comment: @Douglas veja bem, quem define o tipo é a declaração a esquerda. Logo, essa declaração diz que iremos criar uma lista que aceite somente subtipos de Number, isso limita somente o que vamos iniciar do lado esquerdo **e não o que vamos adicionar na lista criada**. Ao adicionar algo a essa lista, não tem como garantir que aquele objeto é permitido na lista, pois um `Double` seria um tipo permitido nessa lista pois herda de Number, mas o compilador não tem como verificar que a lista não permite Double, por isso não permite a adição.

Comment: Modifiquei a pergunta para que deixe de ser duplicata e fique mais especifica a duvida, veja se está ok, qualquer coisa errada, me avise para que eu desfaça a edição.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é o propósito do comando super quando usado na declaração de parametros de um método?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117765/qual-%c3%a9-o-prop%c3%b3sito-do-comando-super-quando-usado-na-declara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-parametros-de)

Comment: @TiagoS Discordo disso ser duplicata. A outra pergunta fala sobre o `? super` e não sobre o `? extends`. A resposta até fala um pouco sobre o `? extends`, mas não entra em maiores detalhes e não fala sobre o problema delineado nesta pergunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adicionar elementos a esse tipo de lista não é possível pois a declaração curinga de `List<? extends Number> ml` significa que a variável `ml` pode conter qualquer valor da família `Number`, em vez de qualquer valor de um tipo específico. Veja as atribuições equivalentes abaixo que seriam permitidas:

```
List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Number>;  // Number "extends" Number
List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Integer>; // Integer extends Number
List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Double>;  // Double extends Number
```

Visto isso, o tipo de objeto que você pode adicionar ao List `foo3` que seria válido depois de qualquer uma das atribuições acima de um `ArrayList` esbarraria nos problemas abaixo:

- Você não pode adicionar um `Integer`porque `foo3` poderia estar apontando para um `List<Double>`.
- Você não pode adicionar um `Double`porque `foo3` poderia estar apontando para um `List<Integer>`.
- Você não pode adicionar um `Number`porque `foo3` poderia estar apontando para um `List<Integer>`.

Portanto:

> Você não pode adicionar qualquer objeto para `List<? extends T>` porque você não pode garantir que `List` está realmente apontando para este tipo, então você não pode garantir que o objeto a ser adicionado é permitido nessa lista. A única "garantia" que você tem é que só pode ler esta lista e vai ter um `T` subclasse de `T`.

A lógica inversa se aplica a utilização do `super`, conforme as atribuições abaixo, que também são válidas:

```
List<? super Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Number>; // Number é "superclasse" de Number
List<? super Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Object>; // Object é "superclasse" de Number
```

Sobre `List<? super T>`, pode-se chegar a seguinte conclusão:

> Você não pode ler o tipo `T` específico(por exemplo `Number`) a partir `List<? super T>` porque você não pode garantir que tipo de `List` está realmente apontando para ele. A única "garantia" que você tem é que você é capaz de adicionar um valor do tipo `T`(ou qualquer subclasse de `T`) sem violar a integridade da lista que está sendo apontado.

A declaração a esquerda(`List<? extends Number> foo3`) define o tipo de dado que poderá ser atribuído a seus ArrayLists a direita(`=  new ArrayList<Integer>();`), e não ao tipo de dado que pode ser adicionado na lista criada.

<sub>*Traduzido e adaptado desta [resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2777297/5524514)*</sub>

---

Referências para leitura:

- [O que são covariância e contravariância?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/28595)
- [Qual é o propósito do comando super quando usado na declaração de parametros de um método?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117765/28595)

Comment: Se não posso adicionar qualquer objeto para List<? extends T> , qual o propósito de criá-la?

Comment: @user2509556 no link da resposta que traduzi do SOen tem essa explicação, dá uma olhada nela. Só não traduzi pra não sair do foco inicial da pergunta