# Generics <? super T> e <? extends T>

Tags: java

No coding abaixo, porque o `Box<? extends T>` usa do extends e o `EqualityComparator<? super T>` usa do super T? de modo a fazer a parte do código `println` retornar verdadeiro?

```java
public boolean containsSame
(Box<? extends T> other, EqualityComparator<? super T> comparator){
return comparator.compare(get(),other.get());
}

public interface EqualityComparator<T> {
public boolean compare(T first, T second);
}



Box<Number> nBox = new Box<Number>(42);
Box<Integer> iBox = new Box<Integer>(42);
EqualityComparator<Object> sameObject = new EqualityComparator<Object>() {
public boolean compare(Object o1, Object o2) { return o1 == o2;} 
};
System.out.println(nBox.containsSame(iBox, sameObject));
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Adicionar elementos a um List<? extends Number>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232339/3774)

Comment: eu li esse post em ingles mas nao consegui entender/relacionar com o exemplo que postei a cima

Comment: Acho que esse também pode ajudar: [Qual é o propósito do comando super quando usado na declaração de parametros de um método?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117935/125486)

Comment: estava lendo exatamente esse post, mesmo assim, eu nao consigo entender o exemplo que postei. Pra eu poder usar .get() em uma lista genérica eu preciso que ela seja do tipo <? Super T> ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando como base [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117935/125486), que inclusive postei nos comentários, posso trazer para essa situação dizendo o seguinte:

Quando você declara o método `containsSame`, dessa forma:

```java
public boolean containsSame(Box<? extends T> other, EqualityComparator<? super T> comparator) {
    //...
}
```

Você está basicamente dizendo que: o parâmetro `other` deve ser um `Box` de objetos de *uma classe-filha* de `T`; e o parâmetro `comparator` deve ser um `EqualityComparator` de objetos *da classe-mãe* de `T`.

Com isso, você criou um objeto, chamado `nBox`, com o tipo `Box<Number>`. Ou seja:

```java
public boolean containsSame(Box<? extends Number> other, EqualityComparator<? super Number> comparator) {
    //...
}
```

Nesse caso, o `T` vai ser `Number`.

---

Depois, você chamou o método `containsSame` de `nBox` e passou como primeiro argumento um `Box<Integer>` e como segundo argumento um `EqualityComparator<Object>`.

Desse modo, não deve haver erros relacionados aos tipos de dados. Pois, as relações definidas nos parâmetros estão sendo atendidas pelos argumentos. Isto é:

- `Integer`(a classe `?`) *é* uma subclasse/classe-filha de `Number` (`T`);
- E `Object` (também a classe `?`) *é* a superclasse/classe-mãe de `Number` (`T`), assim como [de qualquer outra classe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

Portanto, o método executa sem problemas.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado, a ajuda foi imensa, só me resta uma última pergunta, porque o Objeto EqualityCompator precisa ser do tipo super?

Comment: No caso, você pergunta por que que ali no método tem quer ser `<? super T>`?

Comment: suponha que o metodo venha assim, como eu saberia o que devo por para rodar o println sem problemas? `java public boolean containsSame(Box<T> other, EqualityComparator<T> comparator) {
    //...
}`

Comment: Quando você criou o objeto `nBox` no exemplo, você o definiu como sendo um `Box<Number>`. Na definição de sua classe, você deve ter colocado ao lado do nome dela a notação `<T>`. Esse `T` se torna como uma espécie de "apelido" para qualquer classe que seja passada. Nesse caso, `T` se torna um "apelido" para `Number`. Então, nesse caso, onde tiver `T`, você vai considerar como se tivesse `Number` ali.

Comment: Isto é, quando você tiver criado o seu objeto, onde tinha `T`, você vai considerar como se tivesse `Number` no lugar.