# Como chamar um mesmo método com argumentos diferentes mas que herdam da mesma classe mãe?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Tenho duas classes (`ColunaDoGrafico` e `ColunaDoRelatorio`) que estendem de `Coluna`.

A minha classe Coluna tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
public class Coluna  {
    protected String tipoFiltro;
    protected boolean exibeFiltro;
    protected Relatorio relatorio;

    // alguns outros atributos

    //getters e setters
}
```

A classe Relatorio é composta basicamente por:

```
public class Relatorio {
    private Set<ColunaDoRelatorio> colunasDoRelatorio;
    private Set<ColunaDoGrafico> colunasDoGrafico;

    // outros atributos

    public Set<ColunaDoRelatorio> getColunasDoRelatorio() {
        return colunasDoRelatorio;
    }

    public void setColunasDoRelatorio(Set<ColunaDoRelatorio> colunasDoRelatorio) {
        this.colunasDoRelatorio = colunasDoRelatorio;
    }

    public Set<ColunaDoGrafico> getColunasDoGrafico() {
        return colunasDoGrafico;
    }

    public void setColunasDoGrafico(Set<ColunaDoGrafico> colunasDoGrafico) {
        this.colunasDoGrafico = colunasDoGrafico;
    }
}
```

As classes ColunaDoGrafico e ColunaDoRelatorio herdam de Coluna e possuem outros atributos particulares a cada uma.

São basicamente:

```
public class ColunaDoGrafico extends Coluna {

    private String apresentacao;
    private boolean eixoY;
    private boolean eixoX;
    private String operacao;
    //getters and setters
}
```

e:

```
public class ColunaDoRelatorio extends Coluna{
    private boolean exibeNoRelatorio;
    private String operacao;
    private String clausula;
    //getters and setters
 }
```

Em uma outra classe tenho um método que deverá percorrer um set de colunas, que ora poderá ser um Set e ora poderá ser um Set. E esse método deverá analisar dois atributos (que são comuns a ambas classes filhas, já que foi herdado da classe mãe) de cada um dos itens dessa lista. Estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
private void trataFiltro(Set<Coluna> colunas){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(query);
    for(Coluna coluna: colunas){
        if(coluna.isExibeFiltro()){
            if(coluna.getTipoFiltro().equals("texto")){
                System.out.println("A");
            }else if(coluna.getTipoFiltro().equals("dominio")){
                System.out.println("B");            
            }else if(coluna.getTipoFiltro().startsWith("tempo")){
                System.out.println("C");
            }else {
                System.out.println("D");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Porém, quando tento fazer a chamada do método da seguinte maneira:

```
trataFiltro(relatorio.getColunasDoRelatorio());
```

ou

```
trataFiltro(relatorio.getColunasDoGrafico());
```

Não está compilando e diz :

> The method trataFiltro(Set) is not applicable for the arguments Set

Por ambas as classes terem os atributos que são necessários ao método, o código não deveria funcionar? Como posso resolver isso? Tenho que escrever o mesmo método para cada uma das classes, mudando somente o argumento?

Comment: Adicione as duas classes que faltaram tambem.

Comment: já adicionei :)

Comment: Faltou os gets envolvidos no erro.

Comment: coloquei os gets e sets da classe relatorio

Comment: O erro com certeza nao está no codigo apresentado. De onde vem esse metodo ai? Por favor, coloque as classes completas ou se for grande demais, faça um **[mcve]**, com pedaços não da nem pra simular o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando a [resposta do Dudaskank](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288590/132), o motivo pelo qual `Set<? extends Coluna>` resolve é porque um `Set<Coluna>` é um objeto no qual valem essas duas propriedades:

1. Podemos obter itens do tipo `Coluna`. É isso o que você quer.
2. Podemos acrescentar nele itens do tipo `Coluna`. Isso não é algo que você queria.

É por causa dessa segunda propriedade que `Set<ColunaDoGrafico>` e `Set<ColunaDoRelatorio>` não são compatíveis com `Set<Coluna>`. Você não pode acrescentar um tipo qualquer de `Coluna` dentro de um `Set<ColunaDoGrafico>` por exemplo.

A segunda propriedade não é algo que você queira. Você pode abrir mão dela com `Set<? extends Coluna>`. Nesse caso apenas a primeira propriedade vale.

Semelhantemente, se você quiser abrir mão da primeira propriedade e ficar só com a segunda, você usaria `Set<? super Coluna>`.

Answer (score 2):

Mude a assinatura do método para:

```
private void trataFiltro(Set<? extends Coluna> colunas)
```

Segundo a explicação do usuário utluiz♦ [em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117935/61975), isso se chama covariância:

> Só para contextualizar, covariância ocorre quando usamos `extends` e permitimos um tipo mais específico (subclasse) ser usado no lugar de um tipo mais genérico.

Comment: Funcionou! Se vc puder explicar o motivo, ficarei agradecida!

Comment: Funcionou porque dessa forma você força a aceitar todos os subtipos(classe filha) da classe coluna, e nao apenas a classe coluna, como voce estava fazendo.

Comment: ahhhh, mais uma pro meu conhecimento! obrigada!

Comment: @TathianaIanelli Se chama [covariância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117765/28595)

Comment: Mas é estranho isso, pois se o método recebesse apenas uma coluna, ao invés de um set de colunas, funcionaria normalmente. `private void trataFiltro(Coluna c)` ele aceitaria ambos os tipos de colunas.

Comment: mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda Articuno, também não conhecia o termo

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma sobrecarga do método, ou seja faça um método com a mesma assinatura mas que requer argumentos diferentes para que seja executado, ou nenhum argumento, segue o exemplo de uma classe voltada a manipulação de dados com o banco:

```
package mainFiles;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public abstract class DataBaseHandler {

    public abstract boolean create(String field) throws SQLException;
    public abstract ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> read(boolean isOriginal) throws SQLException; //Repare que aqui existe um método que requer um argumento do tipo boolean.
    public abstract ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> read() throws SQLException; //Repare que existe um mesmo método mas que pede argumentos diferentes.
    public abstract boolean update(String field, String values[]) throws SQLException;
    public abstract boolean delete(String field) throws SQLException;

    public Connection dbConfig(Object dbData[]) {
        System.out.println("Iniciando processo de configuração.");
        try {
            System.out.println(dbData[0].toString() + " " + dbData[1].toString() + " " + dbData[2].toString());
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            Connection dbConfiguredConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbData[0].toString(), dbData[1].toString(), dbData[2].toString());
            System.out.println("Banco configurado com sucesso!");
            return dbConfiguredConn;
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao conectar com o banco.");
            Logger.getLogger(Classifier.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

No entanto, da mesma forma que você terá que sobrescrever o método que requer o argumento, terá que sobrescrever o que não requer nenhum. Caso for chama-los, apenas use a mesma assinatura, e passe parâmetros diferentes, ou nenhum parâmetro dependendo da forma como você criou as sobrecargas.