# Laço Forearch como utilizar com controler

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, devexpress, controles

Tenho 6 `PictureEdit` em um `PanelControl`, e preciso executar um lanço em todos os `PictureEdit` então fiz o seguinte código:

```
 foreach (PictureEdit Pic in panel1.Controls)
        {
            //habilita o meno de zoom
            Pic.Properties.ShowZoomSubMenu = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
            //habilita mexer a imagem via mouse
            Pic.Properties.AllowScrollViaMouseDrag = false;
            // habilita zoom com a roda do mouse
            Pic.Properties.AllowZoomOnMouseWheel = DefaultBoolean.False;
            // habilita zoom sem o control
            Pic.Properties.ZoomingOperationMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.ZoomingOperationMode.ControlMouseWheel;
            //definie o sizemode da imagem como clip, obrigatorio para funcionar o zzom
            Pic.Properties.SizeMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.PictureSizeMode.Clip;
            // defini o tamanho de zoom que a imagem é exibida
            Pic.Properties.ZoomPercent = 15;

            // defini o evento mouse wheel, necessario para controlar a velocidade da roda do mouse
            Pic.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(this.pictureEdit1_MouseWheel);
            // defini o evento imagechange, ao editar uma imagem é adicionado a lista de edições
            Pic.ImageChanged += new EventHandler(this.Pic_Change_Edit);
        }
```

Porém, ao executar é exibido o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro Visual Studio]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Forms não possuir *controllers*.

A classe `Panel` é um *containter* para vários controles de todo tipo. Um dos membros desta classe é o `Controls`, conforme usado no código. Ele é uma lisa especializada que possui objetos derivados de `Control`.

Todo tipo derivado de `Control` pode ser automaticamente interpretado como se fosse um `Control`, afinal pelo subtipo, um `PictureEdit` [**é um**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101) `Control`. Como ele herdou tudo de `Control`, certamente existe tudo o que é necessário nele.

O contrário não é verdadeiro. Se um objeto é `Control` ele pode conter **qualquer** derivado dele. Pode ter um `Label` por exemplo. Então se você pega um dos elementos de `panel1.Controls` e ele é um `Label`, como você vai guardar um *label* em `PictureEdit`? Eles são diferentes. Não completamente porque tudo o que veio de `Control` eles possuem em comum, mas a parte específica é diferente, seria uma confusão.

Isto se chama [covariância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/101).

A solução é ler todos os controles e filtrá-los para pegar o que deseja.

```
foreach (var control in panel1.Controls) {
    if (control is PictureEdit) {
        var picture = (PictureEdit)control;
        picture.Properties.ShowZoomSubMenu = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
        picture.Properties.AllowScrollViaMouseDrag = false;
        picture.Properties.AllowZoomOnMouseWheel = DefaultBoolean.False;
        picture.Properties.ZoomingOperationMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.ZoomingOperationMode.ControlMouseWheel;
        picture.Properties.SizeMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.PictureSizeMode.Clip;
        picture.Properties.ZoomPercent = 15;
        picture.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(this.pictureEdit1_MouseWheel);
        picture.ImageChanged += new EventHandler(this.Pic_Change_Edit);
    }
}
```

Se estiver usando C# 7 pode evitar o *cast*:

```
foreach (var control in panel1.Controls) {
    if (control is PictureEdit picture) {
        picture.Properties.ShowZoomSubMenu = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
        picture.Properties.AllowScrollViaMouseDrag = false;
        picture.Properties.AllowZoomOnMouseWheel = DefaultBoolean.False;
        picture.Properties.ZoomingOperationMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.ZoomingOperationMode.ControlMouseWheel;
        picture.Properties.SizeMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.PictureSizeMode.Clip;
        picture.Properties.ZoomPercent = 15;
        picture.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(this.pictureEdit1_MouseWheel);
        picture.ImageChanged += new EventHandler(this.Pic_Change_Edit);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/ChangeControls.cs).