# Uma lista de um tipo não pode se passar por uma lista de seu tipo 'superior'?

Tags: c#, .net, herança, polimorfismo

Existem algumas entidades na aplicação que estou desenvolvendo que precisam ser ordenadas por uma rotina predefinida.

Pensando nisso foi criada classe de contrato, chamada **`ElementoOrdenavel`** e todas as entidades que podem ser ordenadas herdam desta classe.

Ela expõe, *a priori*, somente dois membros. Eis o código da classe.

```
public abstract class ElementoOrdenavel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Ordem { get; set; }
}
```

Exemplo de uma classe que herda desta

```
public class Banner : ElementoOrdenavel
{
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Pra facilitar o meu trabalho, eu fiz um método que recebe uma lista de `ElementoOrdenavel` e faz o trabalho da ordenação, assim

```
void Reorganizar(IEnumerable<ElementoOrdenavel> colecao, int[] idsOrdenados)
{
    for (int ordem = 0; ordem < idsOrdenados.Length; ordem++)
    {
        var elemento = colecao.First(m => m.Id == idsOrdenados[ordem]);
        elemento.Ordem = ordem + 1;
    }
}
```

E tentei chamar este método assim

```
var banners = db.Banners.AsEnumerable();
Reorganizar(banners, ids);
```

E, para minha surpresa, recebi o erro

> cannot convert from '**`IEnumerable<Banner>`**' to '**`IEnumerable<ElementoOrdenavel>`**'

Uma lista de `Banner` não **é** uma lista de `ElementoOrdenavel`?

---

Fazendo um método genérico, funciona normalmente. Por quê?

```
void Reorganizar<T>(IEnumerable<T> colecao, int[] idsOrdenados) where T : ElementoOrdenavel
{
    for (int ordem = 0; ordem < idsOrdenados.Length; ordem++)
    {
        var elemento = colecao.First(m => m.Id == idsOrdenados[ordem]);
        elemento.Ordem = ordem + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Como eu odeio essa herança ;) Não li direito, mas acho que é uma questão de variância: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75097/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56056/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206278/101. A genericidade te dá a garantia que estará ok.

Comment: O primeiro só aceita `IEnumerable<ElementoOrdenavel>`, ou seja tem um polimorfismo dinâmico no `IEnumerable`, mas não há polimorfismo no parâmetro dele. Aí, em C#, a única forma de tornar o parâmetro desta interface polimórfico precisa da generecidade.

Comment: Preciso ver melhor o caso antes de responder, tentarei assim que der tempo

Comment: Também não gosto muito da herança, mas não iria ter outra maneira de fixar o contrato pra fazer um método único sem usá-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covariância é a conversão de um objeto do tipo mais específico `Banner` em um tipo mais genérico `ElementoOrdenavel`. Os operadores só podem ser utilizados em parâmetros de `interfaces` ou `delegates` genéricos.

Poderia ser feito assim:

```
var banners = db.Banners.AsEnumerable();
IEnumerable<ElementoOrdenavel> elemento = banners;
Reorganizar(elemento , ids);
```

Ou, se utilizar uma interface para implementar o `ElementoOrdenavel`:

```
public interface IElementoOrdenavel
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int Ordem { get; set; }
}
public abstract class ElementoOrdenavel: IElementoOrdenavel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Ordem { get; set; }

}
public class Banner : ElementoOrdenavel
{
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}

public class Teste
{
    public static void TesteReorganizar()
    {
        IEnumerable<Banner> a = new List<Banner>() { new Banner(){ Descricao="TESTE", Id = 1, Ordem = 0} };


        Reorganizar(a, new int[] { 1 });
    }

    public static void Reorganizar(IEnumerable<IElementoOrdenavel> colecao, int[] idsOrdenados)
    {

        for (int ordem = 0; ordem < idsOrdenados.Length; ordem++)
        {
            var elemento = colecao.First(m => m.Id == idsOrdenados[ordem]);
            elemento.Ordem = ordem + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Ou, já que não gosta de utilizar heranças, remova a classe `ElementoOrdenavel` e a classe `Banner` e outras herdariam diretamente a `interface` `IElementoOrdenavel`

**Update:**

Refiz o seu código, agora em casa, e para minha surpresa funcionou normalmente. Foi então que resolvi conferir a versão do .NET Framework.

Você deve estar utilizando a versão 3.5, que apresentou o mesmo erro, nas versões superiores já é possível fazer essa conversão diretamente, sem problema algum.

Pesquisando a [Documentação da interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.100).aspx):

Na versão 3.5 ou inferiores, a declaração da interface está assim:

```
public interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable
```

Já a partir da versão 4.0, a declaração está assim:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

***Logo, a covariância definida pela chave `out` só foi implementada a partir da versão 4.0 do .NET Framework***

Comment: Legal sua resposta. Mas tipo, eu quero saber o porquê disso. Resolvido já foi.

Comment: Encontrei mais informações e atualizei a resposta @LINQ

Comment: Você está certo, eu estou usando .NET 3.5 e nem tinha me atentado a isso. Valeu.