# Conversão de lista de interfaces em lista de objetos: (List<Interface> em List<Objeto>)

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, herança, interface

Preciso converter uma `IList<Interface>` em uma `List<Objeto>`.

Veja o exemplo:

```
public interface IObjetosBase
{
     IList<IObjetosBase> get();
}

public class ObjetosBase : IObjetosBase
{
    public virtual IList<IObjetosBase> get() { ... }
}

public class Aluno : ObjetosBase 
{
    public override IList<IObjetosBase> get() { 
      //Aqui eu quero retornar um List<Aluno>
    }
}
```

Códigos de exemplo para efeito didático, pode conter erros

Qual a maneira correta de realizar esta conversão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que deseja fazer não é possível, C# não suporta [covariância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/101) de tipo de retorno. Pode-se pensar em outra solução dependendo do problema, mas na verdade o exemplo é anti didático, então fica até difícil achar uma solução real.

Uma das coisas que pode fazer é criar uma lista com o tipo base mesmo.

```
public interface IObjetosBase {
     IList<IObjetosBase> Get();
}

public class ObjetosBase : IObjetosBase {
    public virtual IList<IObjetosBase> Get() { return new List<IObjetosBase>(); }
}

public class Aluno : ObjetosBase {
    public override IList<IObjetosBase> Get() { return new List<IObjetosBase>() { new Aluno() }; }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/CovarianatReturn.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Não está muito claro o seu problema mas acredito que possa usar a keyword `new` ao invés de sobrescrever o método:

```
 namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public interface IObjetosBase
    {
        IList<IObjetosBase> get();
    }

    public class ObjetosBase : IObjetosBase
    {
        public virtual IList<IObjetosBase> get() { return new List<IObjetosBase>(); }
    }

    public class Aluno : ObjetosBase
    {
        public new IList<Aluno> get()
        {
            return new List<Aluno>();
        }
    }
}
```

Não consegui testar o código agora por falta de tempo, mas também acredito que a classe `Aluno` não deveria retornar uma lista de `Aluno`, Talvez uma Classe `Turma` sim deveria retornar uma lista de `Aluno` ou então, um repositório `Alunos`.

**Edit:**

Ou Você pode popular a lista de `IObjetosBase` com objetos do tipo `Aluno`:

```
public class Aluno : ObjetosBase
{
    public override IList<IObjetosBase> get()
    {
        List<IObjetosBase> lista = new List<IObjetosBase>();
        Aluno obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            obj = new Aluno();
            lista.Add(obj);
        }
        return lista;
    }
}
```

E depois para percorrer os objetos do tipo `Aluno`:

```
    public void Processo()
    {
        IList<IObjetosBase> lista = this.get();
        //Se for necessário checar o tipo do objeto:
        foreach (var obj in lista)
        {
            if (obj is Aluno)
            {
                Aluno a = obj as Aluno;
            }
        }

        //Se não for necessário checar o tipo do objeto:
        foreach (Aluno obj in lista)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: O `new` não gera polimorfismo e parece que ele quer isso.

Comment: pois é, coloquei pra ter uma opção a mais para o colega, o código dele não está muito claro qual é a necessidade mais sempre tento ajudar. Editei e coloquei outra forma que acredito, possa ajuda-lo

Answer (score 1):

Acho que entendi o que queres. Você quer que uma classe tipo Aluno contendo uma lista de interfaces IObjetoBase retorne uma lista de objetos tipo Aluno.

Existem diversas maneiras de fazer isso, e inclusive algumas, se feitas diretamente, podem dar erro de compilação. O mais perto que você poderá chegar disso, ao meu ver, seria: (i) Criando uma função nova GetAlunos; ou (ii) Convertendo o retorno da função para o que você quer.

Duas sugestões plausíveis seguem pelo código abaixo. Nenhuma deu erro de compilação para mim.

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public interface IObjetosBase
    {
        IList<IObjetosBase> Get();
    }

    public class ObjetosBase : IObjetosBase
    {
        protected IList<IObjetosBase> listaObjetosBase;

        public ObjetosBase()
        {
            List<ObjetosBase> objBase = new List<ObjetosBase>(); // Crie uma lista para o tipo de objeto que você deseja
            listaObjetosBase = objBase.Select(ele => ele as IObjetosBase).ToList(); // Converta essa lista para uma lista de interfaces
        }
        public virtual IList<IObjetosBase> Get()
        {
            return listaObjetosBase;
        }
    }

    public class Aluno : ObjetosBase
    {
        public override IList<IObjetosBase> Get()
        {
            return listaObjetosBase;
        }
        public List<Aluno> GetAlunos()  // Implementação alternativa e direta usando Linq
        {
            return listaObjetosBase.OfType<Aluno>().Select(elem => elem as Aluno).ToList();
        }
    }

    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        Aluno alunoQualquer = new Aluno();
        List<Aluno> outrosAlunos;
        // 1ª opção: Selecione os alunos separadamente pelo Get() sobreescrito usando Linq
        outrosAlunos = alunoQualquer.Get().OfType<Aluno>().Select(elem => elem as Aluno).ToList();
        // 2ª opção: Use a função GetAlunos(), que já faz isso por si só
        outrosAlunos = alunoQualquer.GetAlunos();
    }
```

Existem outras formas (ex.: uso de tipos genéricos), mas acho esse método está mais direto e sucinto para seu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Achei seu exemplo extremamente esquisito e nada prático, mas dá pra fazer sim usando tipos genéricos. É o único jeito possível caso você queira manter o polimorfismo e as referências das suas listas.

Veja: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FKVzwE

```
public interface IPessoa<T> where T : IPessoa<T>
{
    string Nome { get; set; }
    IList<T> Get();
}

public class Pessoa<T> : IPessoa<Pessoa<T>> where T : Pessoa<T>
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Pessoa<T>> Get()
    {
        return new List<Pessoa<T>>();
    }
}

public class Aluno : Pessoa<Aluno>
{
    public override IList<Pessoa<Aluno>> Get()
    {
        return new List<Pessoa<Aluno>>();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var aluno = new Aluno();

        IList<Pessoa<Aluno>> alunos = aluno.Get();
        alunos.Add(new Aluno { Nome = "Vítor"});
        alunos.Add(new Aluno { Nome = "Bruno" });

        foreach (Pessoa<Aluno> a in alunos)
            Console.WriteLine(a.Nome);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Você pode ler mais sobre tipos genéricos aqui: http://www.macoratti.net/15/04/c_mgen1.htm