# Porque não posso atribuir uma lista de um tipo mais especifico do que o tipo declarado?

Tags: c#, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho esta classe exemplo:

```
public class User : APerson
    {
        private string _userName;

        [DataMember]
        public virtual string UserName
        {
            get { return _userName; }
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                {
                    throw new FormatException(ErrorMessage.User.USERNAME_REQUIRED);
                }

                if (value.Length > 50)
                {
                    throw new FormatException(ErrorMessage.User.USERNAME_TOO_LONG);
                }

                _userName = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual string Password { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual bool IsActiveDirectory { get; set; } = false;

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual IList<Application> Applications { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual IList<UserAccessKey> UserAccessKeys { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual IList<UserApplication> UserApplications { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual AClient Client { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual IList<UserLog> UserLogs { get; set; }
    }
```

O AClient, é esta classe abstrata:

```
public abstract class AClient
    {
        private string _companyName;
        private string _company;

        [DataMember]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual Guid Hash { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual bool IsManager { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual string CompanyName
        {
            get { return _companyName; }
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length > 100)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ErrorMessage.Client.COMPANY_NAME_TOO_LOG);
                }
                _companyName = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual string Company
        {
            get { return _company; }
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length > 150)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ErrorMessage.Client.COMPANY_TOO_LONG);
                }
                _company = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual string CssFileExtensionName { get; set; }

    }
```

Até aí tudo bem. O problema é que, se eu via LINQ tentar localizar no atributo Client da classe User, o atributo Description, que não existe na classe abstrata, eu terei um erro de compilação.

O que fazer nesses casos? Como explicar para o LINQ qual a classe concreta que herda da classe abstrata, que possui este atributo.

Além disso:
Se eu tiver o seguinte exemplo:

```
public virtual IList<APerson> Patients { get; set; } = new List<Patient>();
```

Eu tenho um erro de compilação, mesmo a classe Patient herdando de APerson.

Se eu fizer isso abaixo, a segunda linha funciona. A primeira não!

```
public virtual IList<APerson> Patients { get; set; } = new List<Patient>();

public APerson person { get; set; } = new Patient();
```

Não consigo entender estes problemas. Alguém pode me dar uma luz?
Obs.: Começando agora com ID.

Comment: Certo, mas seu questionamento não tem relacão com injeção de dependência, consegue colar o conteúdo do erro de compilação na pergunta?

Comment: Não??? Mas na injeção de dependência você da preferência a interfaces e classes abstratas no lugar de classes concretas, não? A minha dúvida é como programar desta forma. Qual categoria indica? E com relação ao erro, não estou na máquina agora mas o erro informa que patient não e um aperson... o mais louco e que se eu fizer um atributo simples, não em lista, ele da certo... Já posto esse exemplo

Comment: Relacionado: [O que são covariância e contravariância?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/2541)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Qual o problema com `List<Animal> lista = new List<Girafa>()` ?

Não funciona pois a classe genérica `List<T>` permite inserir na lista.

Veja, não posso adicionar Camelo numa lista de Girafas:

```
List<Animal> animais = new List<Girafa>();
animais.Add(new Camelo()); // se a lista é de animais,
                           // então deveria ser possível
                           // inserir camelos nela
```

### Usando LINQ com uma lista da classe de base

Se você tem uma lista de `Animal`, e quer tratar apenas os elementos que são `Girafa`, das duas uma:

- Faz um cast de todos os elementos para Girafa:

  ```
  animais.Cast<Girafa>().Select(girafa => girafa.PropriedadeDaGirafa);
  ```
- Seleciona dentre todos os animais, somente os que são `Girafa`:

  ```
  animais.OfType<Girafa>().Select(girafa => girafa.PropriedadeDaGirafa);
  ```

A escolha depende de você saber de antemão que todos os elementos da lista são de fato Girafas ou se podem haver outros animais diferentes na lista.

### Qual é do papo de Variância?

Variância é a forma com que o tipo varia com o parâmetro genérico (é mais fácil entender com os exemplos! =D ).
No C# só se aplica variância a interfaces e delegates genéricos.

- **Covariância:** suponha uma interface `IS<T>`. `IS` e `T` são covariantes quando `IS` varia junto com `T`. Assim sendo isso é válido:

  ```
  Animal a = (Girafa)g;
  IS<Animal> ia = (IS<Girafa>)ig;
  ```
- **Contra-variância:** suponha outra interface `IE<T>`. `IE` e `T` são covariantes é quando `IE` varia contrariamente a `T`. Assim sendo isso é válido:

  ```
  Animal a = (Girafa)g;
  I<Girafa> ig = (I<Animal>)ia;
  ```

Uma questão que sobra é o que faz um tipo ser covariante ou contra-variante com relação ao seu parâmetro?

Ou melhor, que característica do tipo faz os exemplos acima serem verdadeiros?

Vou explicar usando as interfaces dos exemplos acima.

### Covariância - `IS<T>`

Ocorre quando `T` é usado apenas como saída do tipo `IS<T>`. Por isso, se anota o parâmetro genérico com `out`:

```
interface IS<out T>
{
    T LerValor();
}
```

Vamos testar pra ver se vai dar problema:

```
IS<Animal> ia = (IS<Girafa>)ig;
Animal a = ia.LerValor(); // parece bom... IS<Girafa>.LerValor()
                          // retorna Girafa, que é um Animal.
                          // Beleza!
```

### Contra-variância - `IE<T>`

Ocorre quando `T` é usado apenas como entrada do tipo `IE<T>`. Por isso, se anota o parâmetro genérico com `in`:

```
interface IE<in T>
{
    void EscreveValor(T valor);
}
```

Vamos testar pra ver se vai dar problema:

```
IE<Girafa> ig = (IE<Animal>)ia;
ig.EscreveValor( (Girafa)g ); // parece bom... IE<Animal>.EscreveValor()
                              // recebe Animal, então se eu só puder passar
                              // Girafa's tá de boa, pois Girafa é Animal.
                              // Beleza!
```

### Composição de vários níveis de variância

Fica mais fácil entender usando delegates neste caso.

Vou definir eles assim:

```
delegate T DS<out T>();
delegate void DE<in T>(T valor);
```

Vamos a algumas afirmações e alguns códigos para demonstrar:

- A saída da saída é uma saída

  ```
      DS<DS<Girafa>> ssg = () => () => new Girafa();
      DS<DS<Animal>> ssa = ssg;

      // vou receber uma girafa (como sendo um animal)
      Animal a = ssa()();
  ```
- A entrada da saída é uma entrada

  ```
      DS<DE<Animal>> sea = () => a => Console.WriteLine(a);
      DS<DE<Girafa>> seg = sea;

      // vou passar uma girafa (mas o delegate sabe usar qualquer animal)
      var g = new Girafa();
      seg()(g);
  ```
- A saída da entrada é uma entrada

  ```
      DE<DS<Animal>> esa = sa => Console.WriteLine(sa());
      DE<DS<Girafa>> esg = esa;

      // vou passar uma girafa (mas o delegate sabe usar qualquer animal)
      var g = new Girafa();
      esg(() => g);
  ```
- A entrada da entrada é uma saída

  ```
      DE<DE<Girafa>> eeg = eg => eg(new Girafa());
      DE<DE<Animal>> eea = eeg;

      // vou receber uma girafa (através do delegate)
      Animal a;
      eea(a2 => a = a2);
  ```

Tentei fazer uma imagem para explicar, não sei se está confusa, se estiver me falem que eu mudo ou tiro ela.

[image: Composição de níveis de variância]

**Composições titânicas**

Vamos a uns exemplos mais, digamos, complexos:

- A entrada da saída da entrada da entrada... o que seria? Já respondo: é entrada.

  ```
      DE<DE<DS<DE<Animal>>>> eeseg = null;
      DE<DE<DS<DE<Girafa>>>> eesea = eeseg;
  ```
- E a entrada da saída ^5 da entrada da saída da entrada da entrada... o que seria? Direto ao ponto: é saída.

  ```
      DE<DE<DS<DE<DS<DS<DS<DS<DS<DE<Girafa>>>>>>>>>> eesessssseg = null;
      DE<DE<DS<DE<DS<DS<DS<DS<DS<DE<Animal>>>>>>>>>> eesesssssea = eesessssseg;
  ```

É possível responder muito rápido a essas questões. Basta contar as entradas.

- Número par de entradas é saída
- Número ímpar de entradas é entrada

Mas e as saídas?

R: saídas não afetam em nada

- A saída da saída ^10000: é saída pois tem número par de entradas (0 é par)
- A saída ^100 da entrada da saída ^101: é entrada pois possui número ímpar de entradas (apenas 1 entrada)

Comment: Na imagem, você está escrevendo em inglês puro ou tem português? Mais especificamente: e, que língua está o _do_ da imagem?

Comment: Haha... o "do" é português mesmo, é, ficou estranho. O ruim, é que OUT e IN em português ia ficar super longo. Não sei o que fazer... talvez substituir "do" por um "×", ou escrever em inglês mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

O @ramaral indicou nos comentários a pergunta que tem a resposta.

Este problema acontece porque o tipo `Patient` não é covariante em relacão a `APerson`. O que isto quer dizer é que `Patiente` não é um tipo mais genérico que `APerson`.

O problema é que a sua lista de `APerson` não lhe pode garantir que não haverá problemas de execução, quando você tentar adicionar um objeto dum tipo diferente de `Patient` mas que herde de `APerson`.

Já quando você tenta atribuir um `Patient` a uma variável do tipo `APerson` está tudo correto. O tipo `Patient` é contravariante em relacão a `APerson`. Isto quer dizer que ele é sub-tipo de `APerson`. Voce também puderia atribuir qualquer outro sub-tipo que não haveria problemas.

Isto é mais simples entender pelo fato que todos os tipos são contravarientes em relacão a `object`.

Resumindo, a forma de resolver o seu problema é mudar o tipo da lista de pacientes para o tipo genérico `Patient`.

```
public virtual IList<Patient> Patients { get; set; } = new List<Patient>();
```

Também puderia manter a sua lista genérica, mas nesse caso voce nao pode assegurar que só encontrará objetos do tipo `Patient` nela.

```
public virtual IList<APerson> Patients { get; set; } = new List<APerson>();
```