# O que é o parâmetro "in" em um tipo genérico em C#?

Tags: c#

Me deparei com um cenário em C# no qual não entendi muito bem. Estava estudando e vi um trecho de código com um tipo genérico que possui a palavra reservada `in` para esse tipo.

Qual seria a finalidade do uso desse `in` na declaração do Tipo Genérico?

Exemplo do código:

```
public interface IHandler<in T> where T : Message
{
    void Handle(T message);
}
```

Comment: Este artigo da Microsoft acho que explica bem para que serve o `in`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier

Comment: Pelo pouco que li, parece semelhante ao `super` do Java

Comment: Acho que isto já responde, não? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/101. Caso não, dê o contexto onde viu isso.

Comment: Obrigado @JoãoMartins e @Maniero!!