# Não é possível inicializar um objeto genérico com herança

Tags: c#, .net, herança, genéricos, variância

Estou com dificuldade em aceitar uma classe herdada como tipo genérico de uma classe.

```
public class Teste
    {
        private void Testando()
        {
            var dog = new Cachorro();
            dog.Nome = "Toy";
            dog.Patas = 4;
            dog.MesesGestacao = 3;
            dog.Especie = "Cachorro";

            Animal a1 = dog;
            Mamifero m1 = dog;

            Pet<Animal> p1 = new Pet<Cachorro>(); // Esta linha não compila.
        }
    }
    class Animal
    {
        public string Especie { get; set; }
    }
    class Mamifero : Animal
    {
        public int MesesGestacao { get; set; }
    }
    class Cachorro : Mamifero
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public int Patas { get; set; }
    }
    class Pet<T> where T : Animal
    {
        public string Apelido { get; set; }
    }
```

O erro:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

> Error  CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Pet' to 'Pet'

Mas o cachorro é um animal...

Poderiam auxiliar no entendimento do por que isso não funciona?

Como eu poderia converter um `Pet<Cachorro>` em um `Pet<Animal>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa aprender sobre [variância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/101).

Um objeto composto só pode ter a variância de acordo com a herança se for explicitado que isso é permitido, caso contrário ela não é automática.

E há uma outra questão que C# não permitiu o uso de covariância em classes, apenas interfaces e delegados, então terá que implementar essa variância em uma interface e usar em sua classe para que funcione.

Não sei se funcionará como deseja, mas o exemplo não é bom para determinar se na verdade deveria usar outra cosia no lugar. Pode ser que tenha como fazer melhor para o caso específico. Veja funcionando:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var dog = new Cachorro() { Nome = "Toy", Patas = 4, MesesGestacao = 3, Especie = "Cachorro" };
        IPet<Animal> p1 = new Pet<Cachorro>();
    }
}
class Animal {
    public string Especie { get; init; }
}
class Mamifero : Animal {
    public int MesesGestacao { get; init; }
}
class Cachorro : Mamifero {
    public string Nome { get; init; }
    public int Patas { get; init; }
}
interface IPet<out T> where T : Animal {
    public string Apelido { get; init; }
}
class Pet<T> : IPet<T> where T : Animal {
    public string Apelido { get; init; }
}´
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/adkvVP). E [no **repl.it**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/meT954). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/Covariance.cs).